# ssmtp error 501: Could not decode user and password

Tags: email, arch-linux, authentication, smtp, tls

Im trying to send email from cron via `ssmtp` but get the error:

> Authorization failed (501 Could not decode user and password)

**ssmtp.conf**:

```
root=mail@mydomainname.com
mailhub=smtp.zoho.com:465
rewriteDomain=zoho.com
UseTLS=Yes
AuthUser=mail@mydomainname.com
AuthPass=*******
UseSTARTTLS=NO
FromLineOverride=yes
```

User and password are correct. Zoho supports only plain authentication thats why AuthMethod is not set.

What exactly does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed this problem changing the password to an easy one just to test (without special characters).

See my /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:

```
mailhub=smtp.zoho.com:587

# I use my domain. First you have to config the MX records
rewriteDomain=<your domain>.com.br

UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=<your user>@zoho.com
AuthPass=<your pass>
AUTH LOGIN

FromLineOverride=YES
```

See my /etc/ssmtp/realiases:

```
#You have to verify your domain on Zoho and create an email to use
root:<your email>@<your domain>.com.br:smtp.zoho.com:587
```

See [here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/configure-email-delivery.html#alink2) how to config MX records

After that you can test:

```
echo "Test message from Linux server using ssmtp" | sudo ssmtp -vvv dedeco@gmail.com
```

Result:

```
[<-] 220 mx.zohomail.com SMTP Server ready September 27, 2016 8:09:04 PM PDT
[->] EHLO Shun
[<-] 250 SIZE 53477376
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 Ready to start TLS.
[->] EHLO Shun
[<-] 250 SIZE 53477376
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] YW50b25pby5ldXN0YXF1aW9Aem9oby5jb20=
[<-] 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[<-] 235 Authentication Successful
[->] MAIL FROM:<antonio.eustaquio@stratvision.com.br>
[<-] 250 Sender <antonio.eustaquio@stratvision.com.br> OK
[->] RCPT TO:<dedeco@gmail.com>
[<-] 250 Recipient <dedeco@gmail.com> OK
[->] DATA
[<-] 354 Ok Send data ending with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
[->] Received: by Shun (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Wed, 28 Sep 2016 03:09:04 +0000
[->] From: "root" <antonio.eustaquio@stratvision.com.br>
[->] Date: Wed, 28 Sep 2016 03:09:04 +0000
[->] Test message from Linux server using ssmtp
[->] 
[->] .
[<-] 250 Message received
[->] QUIT
[<-] 221 mx.zohomail.com closing connection
```

Comment: A long time ago someone gave a down vote here without any comment. Today was useful for someone! Thank you!